# How do I add vertices to a face for hair simulation?

Tags: particles, faces, subdivision-surface, hair

I want to cover this puzzle piece in a hair simulation but the top and bottom faces don't have enough geometry to emit from. How do I fix this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: By default a particle system has under *Emission > Source >* **Even Distribution** enabled so it should be fine ... to solve your issue we need more info about your setup.